# Dynamic submodule import failing in __main__

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a module that I want to run with `python -m modulename command` with commands referring to submodules launched by importing them. The file layout is as follows:

```
mainmodule/:
  __init__.py (empty)
  submodule1.py
  submodule2.py
  __main__.py
```

with `__main__.py` as follows:

```
import sys, importlib


commands = {"cmd1": "submodule1", "cmd2": "submodule2"}
try:
  cmd = modules[sys.argv[1]]
except IndexError:
  cmd = "cmd1"
except Error:
  pass
module = importlib.import_module("."+cmd, "mainmodule")
```

- `python -m mainmodule` launches `submodule1` as expected;
- `python -m mainmodule cmd1` works;
- `python -m mainmodule.submodule1` works;
- `python -m mainmodule.submodule2` **works too;**

**BUT** `python -m mainmodule cmd2` fails:

```
ImportError: No module named mainmodule.submodule2
```

Why? I've tried changing the `import` value expression in many ways, it always fails in the same way.

Comment: Dictionary lookup fails with `KeyError`, not `IndexError`. Also, `Error` is not a builtin name, you probably meant `Exception`, but there's no need to catch it in your code

Answer (score 0):

Change;

```
  cmd = modules[sys.argv[1]]
```

to

```
  cmd = commands[sys.argv[1]]
```

Other than one typo fix, I can't get the same error. Are you maybe not running python from the directory above `mainmodule`? Or do you maybe not have `mainmodule` installed properly?